# VB.Net datatable, select rows based on maximum values

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable

I am trying to filter rows from a datatable based on the latest date value. Currently I am using dictionary object, which is not suitable for my actual objective, as my datatable will have more than two column, thus invalidating the key,value characteristics of a dictionary object. Bear with my limited knowledge, I am relative new to .net development and learning stuffs myself.

My current coding is

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim names As Dictionary(Of String, DateTime) = New Dictionary(Of String, Date)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim strDetail As String = Nothing

    dt.Columns.Add("Name")
    dt.Columns.Add("punchdate", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))

    dt.Rows.Add("Rajesh", "01-jan-2014")
    dt.Rows.Add("Rajesh", "01-feb-2014")
    dt.Rows.Add("Rajesh", "01-apr-2014")
    dt.Rows.Add("Rajesh", "01-sep-2014")
    dt.Rows.Add("John", "15-sep-2014")


    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        strDetail = row.Item("Name")
        'Debug.WriteLine(strDetail)
        If names.ContainsKey(strDetail) Then
            If names(strDetail) < row.Item("punchdate") Then
                names(strDetail) = row.Item("punchdate")
            End If
        Else
            names.Add(row.Item("Name"), row.Item("punchdate"))

        End If
    Next row

    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, DateTime) In names
        Dim v1 As String = kvp.Key
        Dim v2 As DateTime = kvp.Value

        Debug.WriteLine(v1 + ";   " + v2.ToString)

    Next
End Sub
```

End Module

Please let me know that should be optimal solution based on my requirement to return rows based on the max punchdate and more than just two columns.

regards,

Comment: Dictionaries can contain complex Types for TValue.  For instance, and entire employee or customer record.  So you could store the entire contents of the qualified DT,Row in a `Dictionary(of String, MyClass)`

Comment: Plunotix, thank you. I need to learn more :) Actually my data table will have multiple records for multiple employees, and I need to retrieve the latest record for each employee based on the maximum date available against their records. Can you please point me towards a working code block?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20404431/1070452) might help - the situation is similar.  It at least illustrates a Class object as TValue in a Dictionary.  For the key, I would use something more likely to be unique like an EmpID or something if you just want one record per emp.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have the values in a `DataTable` you can use the [Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Data.DataTable.Compute%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true') method to find the most recent date.

```
Dim maxDt as Object = dt.Compute("MAX(punchdate)", "")
Dim minDt as Object = dt.Compute("MIN(punchdate)", "")
```

In your example `maxDt` would be the most recent entry for "John", "15-sep-2014", and `minDt` would be the oldest entry for "Rajesh", "01-jan-2014".

NOTE: I recommend casting `maxDt` and `minDt` to a Date data type:

```
Dim maxDt as Date = Date.Parse(dt.Compute("MAX(LAST_LOGIN_DATE)", "").ToString())
```

Comment: Hello Dave, I was able to get the maximum date value, however I need to get all the rows from a datatable with their maximum dates, thus returning two rows against my example scenario. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For max punchdate you can use

```
Dim Max1 = rows.Max(Function(r) r.Field(Of <DateTime type>)("punchdate"))
```

and use

```
Dim rows=MyTable.Select("ID=Max1 ")
```

to return the entire row based on the selected max punch date.

if you want to separately select more than one column value for a row independently then you can use

```
TempDt =New DataView(Rows.CopyToDataTable()).ToTable(False, 
"columnname1", "name2","...","..")
```

Comment: Thanks Kaustav, can you please rewrite the code blocks with the columns mentioned with my question. I'm terribly sorry to ask, I couldn't figure out your example against my codes.

Comment: If I am not wrong, you are providing C# code samples, while I need them in VB.Net

Comment: These are all vb.net codes. C# does not have any Dim specifier.

Comment: My bad! I didn't even have enough observation prior making the assumption that the code block was for C#. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

I got it done, following a sample provided [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1826584.aspx?Select%20DataRow%20with%20latest%20date%20using%20LINQ)

and I have modified my code like following & the final code block is as below

```
Imports System.Linq
```

Module Module1
    Dim dt As New DataTable

```
Sub Main()

    ' http://forums.asp.net/t/1826584.aspx?Select+DataRow+with+latest+date+using+LINQ



    dt.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Name")
    dt.Columns.Add("punchdate", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))

    dt.Rows.Add(100, "Rajesh", "01-jan-2014")
    dt.Rows.Add(101, "Rajesh", "01-feb-2014")
    dt.Rows.Add(102, "Rajesh", "01-apr-2014")
    dt.Rows.Add(103, "Rajesh", "01-sep-2014")
    dt.Rows.Add(104, "John", "15-sep-2014")


    ' Dim Max1 = rows.Max(Function(r) r.Field(Of DateTime)("punchdate"))



    Dim myLINQ = From grp In From dt In dt.AsEnumerable() _
                             Group dt By GRP = dt.Field(Of String)("Name") Into Group _
                             Select New With { _
                                 Key .ID = Group.Max(Function(T) T.Field(Of Int32)("ID")), _
                                 Key .Name = GRP, _
                                 Key .[Date] = Group.Max(Function(T) T.Field(Of DateTime)("punchdate")) _
                                            }
    Debug.WriteLine("=======================================")

    For Each g In myLINQ
        ' Debug.WriteLine("Numbers that match '{0}':", g.Name)
        Debug.WriteLine(g.Name & "----->" + g.Date.ToString)

    Next




End Sub
```

End Module

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for you to select an entire row based on the maximum punchdate:

```
Dim Max1 = rows.Max(Function(r) r.Field(DateTime)("punchdate"))
Dim rows=MyTable.Select("punchdate=Max1 ")
```

Alternatively if you want to select records from the datatable in a generic way, then you can use

```
TempDt =New DataView(Rows.CopyToDataTable()).ToTable(False, 
"ID", "Name","punchdate")
```

Comment: Kaustav a stupid question, when I copy the code block provided by in the given order, "rows" shows as not defined, would you please tell me why I get such error?

Comment: If it is giving such errors then you can simply declare Dim rows pervious to this implementation and then use rows to select the rows from the Datatable.